# IIS redirect non www to www

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am struggling this from last couple of days. i have a Asp.Net MVC web application, which i have hosted on IIS. I created website with the name of "www.domain.com".
Now, i want while surfing with the name of "domain.com" should redirect "www.domain.com". I have tried by creating rule followed by https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www. Also by creating canonical domain and writing rules in web.config file. But it's not working.

Any Idea!

Comment: http://www.cembalik.com/iis-url-rewrite-ile-www-yonlendirmesi/ try this.

Comment: tried already, not working